# .NET Core: Synchronous operations are disallowed

Tags: angularjs, .net-core, synchronous, .net-core-3.0

I have an Angular.js app that I am porting to .NET Core.

It was working fine in the previous version of .NET Core 3 preview; 3.2.

However, after upgrading to latest 3.3 some of the get requests are returning this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call
> WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.

I can't see why this is happening with only some requests and not others.

I believe that by default Angular.js does async: xhr.open(method, url, true);

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: did you try setting set AllowSynchronousIO to true?

Comment: This error is described in details in [.NET Core 3.0 AllowSynchronousIO Workaround](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/dotnet-core-3-dot-0-allowsynchronousio-workaround) post by Khalid Abuhakmeh

Answer (score 23):

This problem is described here:  https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8302

The workaround for now is to manually set AllowSynchronous to true in startup.cs;

// Startup.ConfigureServices

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
  options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});
```

Comment: this did not work for me either,  I finally had to convert the code being called to Async (as the error message says,  I used Read/WriteAsync)

Answer (score 17):

It's worth noting that if you host on kestrel directly then your Program.cs should have appropriate ConfigureKestrel call

```
   public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
                {
                    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                })
```

Answer (score 6):

you can disable it for a special method

```
var syncIOFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
if (syncIOFeature != null)
 {
  syncIOFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
 }
```

or disable in all application scope

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            })
```

or in service configure startup

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
  options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a CustomWebApplicationFactory like me, you can set the flag in its constructor, It makes my test direct from VS2019 works.

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup: class
{
    public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
    {
        Server.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error and you're using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` then you can configure it to allow synchronous IO with:

```
builder
    .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        services.Configure<TestServerOptions>(options => options.AllowSynchronousIO = true);
    });
```